# Screen capture of mobile using adb in Power shell

Tags: powershell, adb

i am using power shell programming to take a screen shot of android mobile and show in the gui of PC application that us built using power shell programming...

when screen capture button is clicked..it show error that sc.png does not exists
it means adb command is not capturing screen and save in sd cad....

$buttonTakeScreenCapture_Click={

```
     .\adb.exe shell screencap -p > sc.png 
.\adb.exe pull /sdcard/sc.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use redirection:

```
.\adb.exe shell screencap -p /sdcard/sc.png
.\adb.exe pull /sdcard/sc.png
```